# make an array.push inside a map is getting overwriting previous data (reactJs)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, map-function

I have an Array (A) that return me many items used in the params function of my Api Call, so I made a map with this array, and for each item, I make an API Call and with a .then, with the data response want create a new array (B).

**the problem:**
the array B is made with the same amount of items, but these items are getting repeated, instead of a unique item.

**my code:**

```
useEffect(() => {
  // the Array A in the question \/ // 

    moviesId.arr.map((item) => {

  // the Api Call function in the question \/  //    
 
      ApiMovieList(item).then((data) => {

        let a = [];

        for (var x = 0; x < moviesId.arr.length; x++) {
          a.push(data.poster_path);
        }

     // the Array B in the question \/ //  

         var UserDataEntry = a || [];

        
         console.log(UserDataEntry);
 


      });
    });
  });
```

> Console show this:
>
> ```
>     (2) ["Matrix", "Matrix"] 
>       
>        Instead of this:
>    (2) ["Ghost", "Matrix"]
> ```

How do I solve that, please?

my data:

```
moviesId.arr = ["451048", "436969"]
```

ApiMovieList(item).then((data) => **data is equal a string** ("Matrix", "Ghost", for example, it depends of the position of the moviesId.arr

Comment: `a.push(data.poster_path);` is going to push the same thing into the array. Beyond that, can't say with what you've posted. Include your data.

Comment: I included some information

Comment: @GabrielClaudinoMarinho Not enough, You provided an array of movie ids, Show us all of the api response data, So far it seems `data.poster_path` is just a string. How does looping over an array of ids have anything to do with pushing a string into an array.

Comment: the data.poster_path is different every time that API is called, it is changed by the looping of the array, my problem is I want to get one string, and the next time my Api is called doesn't overwrite my second Array,  but get two different strings. the API response data is just what I say in the question, there is nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `.map` for side-effects. You are iterating `moviesId.arr` array and ***then*** for each element pushing `moviesId.arr.length` number of `data.poster_path` values into array `a`. This is where your duplicates are coming from.

I suggest loading up the `ApiMovieList(item)` calls in an array of Promises and use `Promise.all` to wait for all of them to resolve. You'll then have a resolved array of poster paths to set to `UserDataEntry` and log.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // the Array A in the question
  const posterReqs = moviesId.arr.map(item => {
    return ApiMovieList(item).then(data => data.poster_path);
  });

  Promise.all(posterReqs).then(posters => {
    // the Array B in the question
    const UserDataEntry = posters || []; 
    console.log(UserDataEntry);
  });
});
```